# Extract part of string according to pattern using regular expression Python

Tags: python, regex, string, python-3.x

I have a files that follow a specific format which look something like this:

```
test_0800_20180102_filepath.csv
anotherone_0800_20180101_hello.csv
```

The numbers in the middle represent timestamps, so I would like to extract that information. I know that there is a specific pattern which will always be `_time_date_`, so essentially I want the part of the string that lies between the first and third underscores. I found some examples and somehow similar problems, but I am new to Python and I am having trouble adapting them.

This is what I have implemented thus far:

```
datetime = re.search(r"\d+_(\d+)_", "test_0800_20180102_filepath.csv")
```

But the result I get is only the date part:

```
20180102
```

But what I actually need is:

```
0800_20180101
```

Comment: What have you tried and where did you get stuck?

Comment: I have tried various things but nothing has really worked up to now. The reason why I did not add any minimal example, is that I know it must be something extremely simple with someone that possesses some experience!

Answer (score 5):

That's quite simple:

```
match = re.search(r"_((\d+)_(\d+))_", your_string)

print(match.group(1))  # print time_date >> 0800_20180101
print(match.group(2))  # print time >> 0800
print(match.group(3))  # print date >> 20180101
```

Note that for such tasks the group operator `()` inside the regexp is really helpful, it allows you to access certain substrings of a bigger pattern without having to match each one individually (which can sometimes be much more ambiguous than matching a larger one).

The order in which you then access the groups is from `1-n_specified`, where group `0` is the whole matched pattern. Groups themselves are assigned from left to right, as defined in your pattern.

On a side note, if you have control over it, use unix timestamps so you only have one number defining both date and time universally.

Comment: This is exactly where I have got up to :) but this actually extracts only the date part, not the time part! I need both of them.

Answer (score 1):

They key here is you want everything between the first and the third underscores on each line, so there is no need to worry about designing a regex to match your time and date pattern.

```
with open('myfile.txt', 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        x = '_'.join(line.split('_')[1:3])
        print(x)
```

The problem with your implementation is that you are only capturing the date part of your pattern. If you want to stick with a regex solution then simply move your parentheses to capture the entire pattern you want:

```
re.search(r"(\d+_\d+)_", "test_0800_20180102_filepath.csv").group(1)
```

gives:

```
'0800_20180102'
```

Answer (score -1):

This is very easy to do with `.split()`:

```
time = filename.split("_")[1]
date = filename.split("_")[2]
```